# angular 9 custom table with pagination, filter, sorting performance issue

Tags: angular, typescript, optimization, html-table, pagination

I needed one table with features like pagination, filter (each column), sorting, collapsible row, editable row, fixed total row on bottom but not able to find exact plugin. so i am trying to create my own plugin. i came up with pagination, filter and sort for now. and it is working as expected but it's taking annoyingly too much time to load. on pagination 10 it works ok but above 50 it's take too much time.

**m-table.component.html**

```
<div class="datatable table-responsive">
    <div class="row mb-4">
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="overflow-x: scroll;">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover mb-0" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th *ngFor="let header of headers; let i = index;">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="sort(header)" style="text-decoration: none;">{{settings.columns[header]['title']}}</a>

                            <img class="float-right" src="../../../assets/img/sort-up.webp" *ngIf="sortHeader === header && direction" style="width: 18px;" />
                            <img class="float-right" src="../../../assets/img/sort-down.webp" *ngIf="sortHeader === header && !direction" style="width: 18px;" />
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th *ngFor="let header of headers">{{settings.columns[header]['title']}}</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>

                    <tr>
                        <td *ngFor="let header of headers">
                            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" [(ngModel)]="settings.columns[header]['filter']"
                            (ngModelChange)="filterChangeEvent($event, header)"
                            placeholder="{{settings.columns[header]['title']}}"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr *ngFor="let record of pageOfItems">
                        <td *ngFor="let header of headers">
                            <div *ngIf="!settings.columns[header].type" [ngClass]="settings.columns[header].pill ? 'badge badge-primary badge-pill' : ''">
                                {{record[header]}}
                            </div>
                            <div *ngIf="settings.columns[header].type === 'date'" [ngClass]="settings.columns[header].pill ? 'badge badge-primary badge-pill' : ''">
                                {{record[header] | date: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'}}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="px-4">
                <app-pagination [items]="dataCopy" [settings]="settings.pager"  (changePage)="onChangePage($event)"></app-pagination>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**m-table.component.ts**

```
export class MTableComponent implements OnInit {
    filterQuery: string;
    filterQueryChanged: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

    @Input() data;
    @Input() settings;

    dataCopy = [];
    pageOfItems: Array<any>;
    siteName = '';
    headers = [];
    direction = false;
    sortHeader = '';

    constructor() {

        this.filterQueryChanged.pipe(debounceTime(2000), distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe(query => {
            this.filterQuery = query;
            this.dataCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data));
            for(let key in this.settings.columns) {
                if(this.settings.columns[key]['filter'] && this.settings.columns[key]['filter'] != '') {
                    this.dataCopy = this.dataCopy.filter(a => a[key].toLowerCase().includes(this.settings.columns[key]['filter'].toLowerCase()));
                }
            }
        });

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {}

    ngOnChanges() {
        this.dataCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data));
        this.headers = Object.keys(this.settings.columns);
    }

    filterChangeEvent(search, column) {
        this.filterQueryChanged.next(search);
    }

    compareValues(direction: any, a: any, b: any) {
        if (a < b) {
            return -1 * direction;
        }
        if (a > b) {
            return direction;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    sort(header: string) {
        if(this.sortHeader === header) {
            this.direction = !this.direction;
        } else {
            this.direction = false;
        }
        this.sortHeader = header;
        const dir: number = this.direction ? 1 : -1;
        const compare: Function = this.compareValues;
        let dataCopy = this.dataCopy.sort((a, b) => {
            return compare.call(null, dir, a[header], b[header]);
        });
        // did this because pagination was not detecting changes
        this.dataCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dataCopy));
    }

    onChangePage(pageOfItems: Array<any>) {
        this.pageOfItems = pageOfItems;
    }
}
```

**pagination.component.html**

```
<div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" *ngIf="pager.pages && pager.pages.length">
    <div class="float-left">
        <div>
            <span class="float-left" style="padding-top: 7px;">Showing {{pager.startIndex + 1}} to {{pager.endIndex + 1}} of {{pager.totalItems}} entries</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="float-right">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li [ngClass]="{disabled:pager.currentPage === 1}" class="page-item first-item">
                <a (click)="setPage(1)" class="page-link">
                    <i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li [ngClass]="{disabled:pager.currentPage === 1}" class="page-item previous-item">
                <a (click)="setPage(pager.currentPage - 1)" class="page-link">
                    <i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li *ngFor="let page of pager.pages" [ngClass]="{active:pager.currentPage === page}" class="page-item number-item">
                <a (click)="setPage(page)" class="page-link">{{page}}</a>
            </li>
            <li [ngClass]="{disabled:pager.currentPage === pager.totalPages}" class="page-item next-item">
                <a (click)="setPage(pager.currentPage + 1)" class="page-link">
                    <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li [ngClass]="{disabled:pager.currentPage === pager.totalPages}" class="page-item last-item">
                <a (click)="setPage(pager.totalPages)" class="page-link">
                    <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="float-right mr-3" style="margin-top: 3px;">
        <select [(ngModel)]="settings.pageSize" (ngModelChange)="setPage(initialPage)" class="form-control form-control-sm" style="width: 160px;">
            <option *ngFor="let pageSize of settings.pageSizeOptions" [value]="pageSize">{{pageSize}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>

</div>
```

**pagination.component.ts**

```
export class PaginationComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() items: Array<any>;
    @Output() changePage = new EventEmitter<any>(true);
    @Input() initialPage = 1;
    @Input() settings = {
        pageSize: 100,
        pageSizeOptions: [100, 200, 500],
        maxPages: 5
    };

    pager: any = {};

    ngOnInit() {
        if (this.items && this.items.length) {
            this.setPage(this.initialPage);
        }
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        if (changes.items.currentValue !== changes.items.previousValue) {
            this.setPage(this.initialPage);
        }
    }

    setPage(page: number) {
        this.pager = paginate(this.items.length, page, this.settings.pageSize, this.settings.maxPages);
        var pageOfItems = this.items.slice(this.pager.startIndex, this.pager.endIndex + 1);
        this.changePage.emit(pageOfItems);
    }
}
```

**paginate.ts**

```
export default function paginate(
totalItems: number,
currentPage: number = 1,
pageSize: number = 10,
maxPages: number = 10
) {
    let totalPages = Math.ceil(totalItems / pageSize);
    if (currentPage < 1) {
        currentPage = 1;
    } else if (currentPage > totalPages) {
        currentPage = totalPages;
    }

    let startPage: number, endPage: number;
    if (totalPages <= maxPages) {
        startPage = 1;
        endPage = totalPages;
    } else {
        let maxPagesBeforeCurrentPage = Math.floor(maxPages / 2);
        let maxPagesAfterCurrentPage = Math.ceil(maxPages / 2) - 1;
        if (currentPage <= maxPagesBeforeCurrentPage) {
            startPage = 1;
            endPage = maxPages;
        } else if (currentPage + maxPagesAfterCurrentPage >= totalPages) {
            startPage = totalPages - maxPages + 1;
            endPage = totalPages;
        } else {
            startPage = currentPage - maxPagesBeforeCurrentPage;
            endPage = currentPage + maxPagesAfterCurrentPage;
        }
    }

    let startIndex = (currentPage - 1) * pageSize;
    let endIndex = Math.min(startIndex + pageSize - 1, totalItems - 1);

    let pages = Array.from(Array((endPage + 1) - startPage).keys()).map(i => startPage + i);

    return {
        totalItems: totalItems,
        currentPage: currentPage,
        pageSize: pageSize,
        totalPages: totalPages,
        startPage: startPage,
        endPage: endPage,
        startIndex: startIndex,
        endIndex: endIndex,
        pages: pages
    };
}
```

I am not able to figure out what is wrong and how to improve it. anything would be helpful, thank you.

demo 
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lphy8d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz demo? actually there is a different scenario where it impacts performance (API side, while fetching data, while binding data) etc.

Comment: actually i tried without api integration, hard-coded JSON also generates same behaviour

Comment: Can you provide that demo (With hard coded JSON)?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lphy8d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: unable to reproduce performance issue! Can you suggest the steps or add more related data which is impactable

Comment: i have updated the JSON to 11k records and it's working fine in stackblitz, i don't understand maybe i have done something wrong with my project setup i guess

Comment: I have also not noticed any performance issues. Are you sure your 2 seconds of debounce time is not throwing you off...

Comment: no, when I change pagination limit to 100 immediately page gets lag for like 10 seconds. not able to click on anything.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I don't have performance issues on my computer. However, usually, the reason for the tables' bad performance is the fact that you should render a lot of DOM content on your page. To optimize it, you can implement `virtual-scroll` feature for your table. 
Or use one of these tables that already has it:

1) https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

2) https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable

Comment: thank you for your reply but as i mention i can't find exactly what i want in third party plugins that's why i am implementing custom table.